# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './component/Hello'

Tags: reactjs, webpack, sails.js, babeljs

I´m trying to import a simple Component but the webpack seems to cant find it. The route is good and the "resolve" in the webpack config is great too, therefore I cant understand where is the issue.
Give it at look please.
By the way, its a Sails/React environment.

ERROR in ./assets/src/component/Hello.jsx 6:12
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (6:12)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file.

Hello.jsx:

```
import React from 'react'

class Hello extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <div> // Err supposed to be here (line6)
                Hello World!
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Hello;
```

index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Hello from './component/Hello'

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      Simple Sails-React stater
      <Hello/>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

.babelrc:

```
{
   "presets": ["@babel/env", "@babel/react"]
}
```

webpack config file:

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    entry: './assets/src/index.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/.tmp/public',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        use: 'babel-loader',
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
        test: /\.css$/
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx']
  },

  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'assets/src/index.html'
    })
  ]
};
```

the structure is like this:

```
-src
--component
----Hello.jsx
--index.js
--index.html
```

Comment: It worked somehow.. But would like to use the .jsx extension tho.. @mialnika

Answer (score 1):

Could you try change extension to Hello.js or change bable-loader test to

```js
test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
```

Comment: It worked both ways! Thank You! But I dont get it. I mean, isnt the "resolve" from webpack doing the same thing that "test"?

Comment: Great :) according to your question not really - resolve tells you only how modules are resolved but on test you define which module should handle it.

Comment: Got it. Thank you again!

Comment: No problem :) have nice day!